# I want to memcpy directly into a struct, but none of the methods are avoiding the padding issue correctly

Tags: c++, c++11, memcpy

I'm trying to open a binary file and read the Header from it. I'm able to read it in a series of integers, but I decided to convert it into a struct to allow for n-number of objects. However, I'm facing different issues each time, and they're all about the padding that structs introduce.
When I tried

```
struct {
int x1;
int x2;
long long x3;
long long x4;
} info;
```

I ran into an issue where x1 and x2 are followed by a padding of size 4.

When I tried

```
struct {
uint32 x1;
uint32 x2;
uint64 x3;
uint64 x4;
} info;
```

I ran into an issue where the sizeof(info) is returning a size greatly larger than the first struct. I wanted to try pragma pack but I want a universal Windows solution that doesn't rely on Visual Studio.
I know about ordering the declarations correctly to avoid the padding, but the problem is that the order is important, since I'm reading a binary file using `memcpy(&info, bytes_array, sizeof(info))`.

I would like to get advice on how to accomplish this properly, even if it meant that I have to change how my struct looks like.

My current code:

```
unsigned int read_size = sizeof(info);
char* read_array = new char [read_size];
fin.read(read_array, read_size);

memcpy(&info, read_array, read_size);
```

Comment: if on GCC, use `struct __attribute__ ((packed))`

Comment: guess there is no way around `#pragma pack(push, <numOfBytes>)`

Comment: who wrote that binary file? maybe [bitfields](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) can help

Comment: struct layout is always compiler-dependent.  If you need a particular binary layout, there is no way around compiler-specific features.  Otherwise, read the data objects one-by-one and fill in the struct yourself.

Comment: Is `sizeof(int) == 2`?  If the `int` members are 4 bytes each, there's no obvious reason for any padding between `x2` and `x3` in the first structure (or between `x1` and `x2`).  How did you establish that the padding was there?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `sizeof(int)` returns 4, but so does `sizeof(long int)`. I'm using `mingw-32` as my g++ compiler. using `struct {uint64_t unkown;uint64_t dec_size;uint64_t st_offset;uint64_t seg_size;}info;` gives size 0x28 even though it should return 0x20.

Comment: @NateEldredge isn't there a universal directive that tells the compilers to ignore padding in a region?

Comment: @thethiny: No, there is not, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Don't fight padding. Use a serialization library like Protobuf https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers

Comment: I'm surprised because that would seem to break compatibility with C.  If these were classes with member functions, especially virtual member functions, then I'd be unsurprised — there'd be a vtable or something similar occupying the extra space.  However, they were comments for a reason: I wasn't sure.

Comment: I made a test with gcc (7.4.0). Get a `info` size of 24 bytes. So no padding ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The layout of structs is always compiler-dependent, and there isn't any universal way to force a particular layout.  Most compilers do have some sort of `pack` directive, whether via `#pragma` or `__attribute__` or something else, but there is no single way that will work for all compilers.

If you want a more compiler-independent solution, then don't copy into the entire struct; do one member at a time:

```
unsigned int read_size = 24;  // use explicit size, not sizeof(info)
char* read_array = new char [read_size];
fin.read(read_array, read_size);

info i;

memcpy(&i.x1, read_array, 4);
memcpy(&i.x2, read_array+4, 4);
memcpy(&i.x3, read_array+8, 8);
memcpy(&i.x4, read_array+16, 8);
```

Note that the compiler should optimize these `memcpy()`'s pretty well.

You'll want to verify that the types you're using actually have sizes that match what's in the binary, as well as ensuring that they have the correct byte order.